# Change Audio Pitch with Audio Speed Ffmpeg

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, pitch, sample-rate

i'm using `Ffmpeg` to change Audio `Pitch` and `Speed` and here's some command i'm trying:

1. `ffmpeg -i audioPath -filter:a atempo=audioSpeed,asetrate=audioPitch -ar sampleRate -b:a xValue(k) output.mp3`
2. `ffmpeg -i audioPath -filter:a atempo=(audioSpeed / audioPitch),asetrate=(sampleRate * audioPitch),aresample=sampleRate`

and i tried some more commands also with little bit of changes.

(here `audioSpeed` and `audioPitch` are in range of `0.5` to `2.0`, `sampleRate` is between `8000` to `48000` and `bitRate` is between range of `96k` to `320k`)

Now let's talk about the problem, if we only use `atempo`, it will change audio speed and if we use `asetrate`, it will change `audio pitch` along with `speed` and looks like it will ignore `audioPitch` value if we do something like - `samplerate * audioPitch` (if i use `sampleRate = 8000` audio speed will decrease with thick voice and if `sampleRate = 48000` audio speed will increase with thin voice(with means `audioPitch` will adjust according to `sampleRate`, as of i experienced from output audios))

What i want is if i change `audioSpeed` to `0.5` and `audioPitch` to `2.0`, then in output file speed will decrease and pitch will be also applied plus i have to change `frequency(sample rate)` and `bitrate`..

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you..

Comment: asetrate accepts a sampling rate, not a ratio.

Comment: do you mean by `"atempo=" + audioSpeed + ",asetrate=" + sampleRate` or only `"asetrate=" + sampleRate`?

Comment: @Gyan ohk, basically what i want is, i have to change audio `speed` and `pitch` along with `bitrate` and `frequency/sample rate`, can you please help me to complete this command??